# Celery Active Task lost on worker shutdown

Tags: python, django, celery, django-celery, celery-task

I am using celery=4.0.0, when a task runs for a longer period and worker shutdown in between that, i lost all those task. How to re-initiate all the lost task. Thanks in advance.
celery = 4.0.0
redis = 2.10.5

Comment: This should be helpful - http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/brokers/redis.html#visibility-timeout  
Do read the caveats.

Answer (score 0):

You should override celery signal methods.
Signal list; http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/signals.html

Create a model for celery tasks. For example it's name is CeleryTask.
Before task is run, create new task object in CeleryTask model. When celery restarted and when worker is ready, tasks are run again.

**tasks.py**

```
from celery.signals import worker_ready, task_prerun

def on_task_prerun(*args, **kwargs):
    from .models import CeleryTask

    task_properties = kwargs['task']

    ctask = CeleryTask.objects.create(
        task_name=task_properties.name,
        task_args=task_properties.request.args
    )

def on_worker_ready(*args, **kwargs):
    from .models import CeleryTask
    from celery.execute import send_task

    tasks = CeleryTask.objects.all()

    for ctask in tasks:
        send_task(ctask.task_name, ctask.task_args)

worker_ready.connect(on_worker_ready, dispatch_uid='on_worker_ready')
task_prerun.connect(on_task_prerun, dispatch_uid='on_task_prerun')
```